# {"Cannot find column [Firstname]."}

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataset)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Firstname Like '%{0}%'", search_txt.Text)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = DV
```

My goal is to search data in datagridview using textbox (search_txt) but there is an error

Comment: Are you sure that there is a column "Firstname"?

Comment: Do you have multiple Tables in your DataView? If so you have to provide the tablename infront of the attribute: `Table.Firstname Like '%{0}%'`

Comment: yes I have Firstname column and I only have one table in Dataview, it is working before but when I run it again it shows an error

Comment: use the debugger, you don't have a column with that name in the DataTable named dbDataset. That's for sure and thus the error is not here

Comment: Dim Query As String = "select Patient_Id, Surname, Firstname, MI, Address, Age, Gender, Email, Contact_No from database.patient_info"

that is my query

Comment: @EdreyChing are you able to use a debugger? If yes put a breakpoint on the DataView constructor. Move the mouse over the dbDataset table and look at its members, in particular to the Columns collection.

Comment: @Steve I dont know how to use the debuger ? can you teach me ?

Comment: No, this is not the place for a tutorial on a such broad argument. There are well done tutorials and instructions made by a lot more qualified people than me. Starting from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: @Steve btw thank you for your comment, I found what makes it error through your suggestion and now its running smoothly thanks!

Comment: Well done. If you think that your solution is of help to future readers don't hesitate to post your own answer detailing what were the cause and the fix

Answer (score 0):

Type this in after double-clicking the textbox to go to its `.TextChanged` event handler:

```
Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text

Try
    If Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim(" ") = " " Then
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To DictionaryDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To Me.DictionaryDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells.Count - 1
                If DictionaryDataGridView.Item(j, i).Value.ToString().ToLower.StartsWith(str.ToLower) Then
                    DictionaryDataGridView.Rows(i).Selected = True
                    DictionaryDataGridView.CurrentCell = DictionaryDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j)
                    Exit Try
                End If
            Next
        Next i
    End If
Catch abc As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry!")
End Try
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).